# Set integer value in a column for threshold integer in another column?

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

The objective is to set an integer threshold using values from Column B and recording those thresholds in Column C. The thresholds are -1 and 1 in Column B  concluding upon crossing 0, to record values of -1 and 1 in Column C. The resulting DataFrame will be:

```
    A     B      C      
 1  D   0.25     0      
 2  D   0.50     0      
 3  D   0.75     0     
 4  D   1.00     1      
 5  D   1.25     1      
 6  D   1.75     1      
 7  D   0.50     1     
 8  D  -0.25     0      
 9  D   1.25     1      
10  D   0.75     1      
11  D  -0.75     0      
12  D  -1.00    -1      
13  D  -1.50    -1      
14  D  -2.00    -1      
14  D  -0.75    -1      
14  D   0.00     0
```

So far I have tried an implementation with .bins() for the DataFrame, but it does not really iterate through or comprehend the series, rather just setting values for bins. This code is:

```
df['C'] = 0

bins = [-1,0, 1] #with values from df['B']

group_names = [-1,0, 1] #with values from df['B']

g = pd.cut(group_em['B'], bins, labels = group_names)
g= g.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this, use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['C'] = np.where(df.B >= 1, 1,              # if B >= 1 then C is 1
          np.where(df.B <= -1, -1,            # if B <= -1 then C is -1
          np.where(np.sign(df.B).diff() != 0, 0, np.nan)))    # else if B changes sign 
          # (cross zero) then C is 0 otherwise C is nan

df.ffill()                                    # fill nan with previous values

#   A       B      C
#1  D    0.25    0.0
#2  D    0.50    0.0
#3  D    0.75    0.0
#4  D    1.00    1.0
#5  D    1.25    1.0
#6  D    1.75    1.0
#7  D    0.50    1.0
#8  D   -0.25    0.0
#9  D    1.25    1.0
#10 D    0.75    1.0
#11 D   -0.75    0.0
#12 D   -1.00   -1.0
#13 D   -1.50   -1.0
#14 D   -2.00   -1.0
#14 D   -0.75   -1.0
#14 D    0.00    0.0
```

Comment: Great, this solution is correct as implemented. A quick note, at least for my code: I have to assign df['C'] = df['C'].ffill(). An addition to this problem I will implement next is a linear integer assignment, instead of -1 and 1. This will maintain the thresholds, but change Column C values to scale linearly based off prop osed Column D while df['C'] = -1 or 1. Thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helps. Yes you need to assign the column back. `ffill` doesn't modify column in place.